# Does the package csvsimple support auto pagination?

Tags: tables, page-breaking, csvsimple

I have a csv file that will probably take two pages, and doing 
`\csvautotabular{Foo.csv}` just makes my table run off the page.

I checked the documentation but did not see anything about pagination of tables.

Does anyone know if there's a way to make it automatically break the table across page boundaries?

I am also open to using alternate packages for importing CSV's if they solve this problem well.

Answer (score 5):

I was searching for "pagination", and "pages" in the documentation, but apparently I just needed to use `\csvautolongtable` instead.